# current playback position doesn't change on html video

Tags: javascript, html, video

I have an html5 video player residing on a mvc3 razor view. I have had the video playing just fine, but weirdly I can't seem to change the playback position(time) with the slider control of the `video` element. I make my move to change the playback position with mouse but it just goes on from where it left.

I thought I should have right some extra javascript to handle video seeking, but it's just nonsense isn't it? What am I missing here?

Below is the html I have.

```
<video id="presentedFile" width="780" height="510" controls>
    <source src="/Folder/GetVideoStream?videoId=3" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

**Edit:** I have figured that when I have the source as an actionlink to my mvc controller this problem occurs. If I get the file directly from the file it works as I expected. So there must be something wrong with my controller.

```
public FileResult GetVideoStream( string videoId )
{
    /// create my stream
    return File(myStream, MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(myVideo));
}
```

Comment: what is the url returned. If it's absolute then it works else won't work for a relative

Comment: when I give the url to browser it starts to download the file. I create the stream myself, so it is not a file that I can give an absolute path of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11837681/html5-video-from-mvc3-action-not-working-correctly) answer, I managed overcome this problem. Figured it is the missing http headers `accept-ranges` and `content-range` on the response which causing undraggable videos.

Just for the simplification of the mentioned solution on above link, they have used an http handler to solve the problem. But I would like to state that using implementing an http handler is not a part of the required solution. The solution is that you have to put necessary headers to the response like below:

```
public FileResult GetVideoStream( string videoId )
{
    /// create the stream

    /// if request contains range details
    if ( !String.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_RANGE"]) )
        SetHeadersForRangedRequests(stream, HttpContext);

    return File(myStream, MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(myVideo));
}
```

Following method is quoted from the link above, I just removed the `using` around the `StreamReader` since I need the stream to be left open after the operation is done.

```
void SetHeadersForRangedRequests ( Stream stream, HttpContextBase context )
{
    long size, start, end, length, fp = 0;
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);

    size = reader.BaseStream.Length;
    start = 0;
    end = size - 1;
    length = size;

    context.Response.AddHeader("Accept-Ranges", "0-" + size);

    if ( !String.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_RANGE"]) )
    {
        long anotherStart = start;
        long anotherEnd = end;
        string[] arr_split = context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_RANGE"].Split(new char[] { Convert.ToChar("=") });
        string range = arr_split[1];

        // Make sure the client hasn't sent us a multibyte range
        if ( range.IndexOf(",") > -1 )
        {
            // (?) Shoud this be issued here, or should the first
            // range be used? Or should the header be ignored and
            // we output the whole content?
            context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Range", "bytes " + start + "-" + end + "/" + size);
            throw new HttpException(416, "Requested Range Not Satisfiable");
        }

        // If the range starts with an '-' we start from the beginning
        // If not, we forward the file pointer
        // And make sure to get the end byte if spesified
        if ( range.StartsWith("-") )
        {
            // The n-number of the last bytes is requested
            anotherStart = size - Convert.ToInt64(range.Substring(1));
        }
        else
        {
            arr_split = range.Split(new char[] { Convert.ToChar("-") });
            anotherStart = Convert.ToInt64(arr_split[0]);
            long temp = 0;
            anotherEnd = ( arr_split.Length > 1 && Int64.TryParse(arr_split[1].ToString(), out temp) ) ? Convert.ToInt64(arr_split[1]) : size;
        }
        /* Check the range and make sure it's treated according to the specs.
            * http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html
            */
        // End bytes can not be larger than $end.
        anotherEnd = ( anotherEnd > end ) ? end : anotherEnd;
        // Validate the requested range and return an error if it's not correct.
        if ( anotherStart > anotherEnd || anotherStart > size - 1 || anotherEnd >= size )
        {

            context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Range", "bytes " + start + "-" + end + "/" + size);
            throw new HttpException(416, "Requested Range Not Satisfiable");
        }
        start = anotherStart;
        end = anotherEnd;

        length = end - start + 1; // Calculate new content length
        fp = reader.BaseStream.Seek(start, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        context.Response.StatusCode = 206;
    }

    // Notify the client the byte range we'll be outputting
    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Range", "bytes " + start + "-" + end + "/" + size);
    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", length.ToString());
}
```